# What is this airplane I saw with propellers behind the engine and canards on the top of the plane?

Tags: aircraft-identification

While playing Pokémon GO, I saw a plane with:

- Propellers behind the engine.
- Canards at the tip of the plane.
- Normal-looking tail with a flat wing at the end of the upright bit.

I know these are probably not the correct terms, but I'm not sure what else to call those components.

Comment: Could it be a VariEze? https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rutan_VariEze

Comment: The terms you're looking for: "Propellers behind the engine": this is a [pusher configuration](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pusher_configuration).  "Normal looking tail with a flat wing at the end of the upright bit": this sounds like a [T-tail](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/T-tail).

Answer (score 22, accepted):

The "propellers behind the engine" is called a "push configuration". One you look through aircraft that are private business planes, the [Piaggio P.180 Avanti](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Piaggio_P.180_Avanti) comes up as a likely contender.

[image: the p.180 Avanti banking on a turn]

Comment: The stabilizer arrangement here is usually called a "three-surface" -- both canard and conventional stabilizer in addition to the main wing.  There are a number of current and next generation jet fighters with this layout, as well, though of course they don't have pusher propellers.

Comment: Could have been a Beechcraft Starship too, I don't have a picture on hand. Large plane or small?

Comment: The Starship does not have a "normal looking tail", though.

Comment: @CrossRoads I'm begining to wonder if that was it? [Picture](https://sportysnetwork.com/airfacts/files/2018/01/1024px-Beechcraft_Starship_in_flight.jpg).

Comment: The second thing on the Starship ID checklist after the rear-facing engines, is the winglets.  This has none.